# DStream to Rdd in Spark-Straming

Tags: scala, type-conversion, spark-streaming, rdd, dstream

I have a `DStream[String,String]` and I need to convert it to `RDD[String,String]`. Is there any way to do it? I need to do using `Scala` language.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A DStream is a discretized sequence of RDDs. Take a look to the direct stream API.

Having your DStream,with the forEach function you can apply transformations for each RDD:

```
val yourStream: DStream[String] = //...

yourStream.forEachRDD{ rdd =>
   // your rdd transformations...
}
```

You can take a look to examples [here](https://www.programcreek.com/scala/org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream)